# I am trying to set up a subquery

Tags: sql

I am trying to see how I can write a subquery. I have a table called supplier. The fields are supplierid, name, ordervalue and orderid. I need to write a query that will produce all the suppliers that has order ordervalue > 1000000 more than 10 times.

```
select name, count(*)
from (select orderid from supplier where ordervalue >1000000 group by 
orderid) 
where count(*) > 10
group by name;
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error? If so, what DBMS are you using. In In postgres, you would be required to name the subquery, as in (SELECT orderid ....) bigorders

Comment: You do not need a subquery for this, so this is a bad example.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI way of writing this query which should work in most RDBMS (at least in SQL Server and in Oracle):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(orderid)
FROM   supplier 
WHERE  ordervalue > 1000000
GROUP  BY name
HAVING COUNT(orderid) > 10;
```